# How to limit the information retrieved from an eloquent query and stop it crashing?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

The following code, goes through the entire company database and cache's the lower level nested relationships so that they can be accessed at a later date. This eats a massive amount of memory and dies, when the data gets past ~20,000 or so companies and ~500,000 nested relationships. How can I modify it (change it to raw SQL or Laravel query builder statements), so that it loads only the the information I need and its performance increases? (enough to count the entries status).

The nested relationships are as follows

1. Companies > (has many) Locations > (has many) Equipment > (has
   many) Projects > (has one) Order
2. Companies > (has many) Agreements > (has many) Equipment
3. Companies > (has many) Leads
4. Companies > (has many) Invoices

The script should output the count of the following things for each company

1. maintainedCount - the number of active equipment (i.e. with a status
   of 'Active') on an active agreement (i.e. with a status of
   'Unsigned', 'Active' or 'Cancel on Expiry')
2. equipmentCount - the number of active pieces of equipment (i.e. with
   a status of 'Active')
3. leadCount - the number of active leads (i.e. with a status of
   'Open')
4. invoiceCount - the number of active invoices (i.e. with a status of
   'Pending' or 'Complete')
5. projectCount - the number of active projects (i.e. with a status of
   'Pending' or 'Complete')
6. orderCount - the number of active orders (i.e. with a status of
   'Pending' or 'Complete')

Current script is below;

```
Company::chunk(50, function($companies) {
  foreach ($companies as $company) {
    $maintainedCount = 0;
    $equipmentCount = 0;
    $leadCount = 0;
    $invoiceCount = 0;
    $projectCount = 0;
    $orderCount = 0;
    foreach ($company->agreements as $agreement) {
      if (in_array($agreement->status, ['Unsigned', 'Active', 'Cancel on Expiry'])) {
        $maintainedCount += $agreement->equipment->where('status', 'Active')->count();
      }
    }
    $equipmentCount = $company->equipment->where('status', 'Active')->count();
    $unmaintainedCount = ($equipmentCount - $maintainedCount);
    $leadCount= $company->leads->where('status', 'Open')->count();
    foreach ($company->invoices as $invoice) {
      if (in_array($invoice->status, ['Pending', 'Complete'])) {
        $invoiceCount += 1;
      }
    }    
    foreach ($company->equipment as $equipment) {
      foreach ($equipment->projects as $project) {
        if (in_array($project->status, ['Pending', 'Complete'])) {
          $projectCount += 1;
        }
        if($project->order <> null) {
          if (in_array($project->order->status, ['Pending', 'Complete'])) {
            $orderCount += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    DB::table('companies')->where('id', $company->id)->update(['unmaintained_count' => $unmaintainedCount, 'lead_count' => $leadCount, 'project_count' => $projectCount, 'order_count' => $orderCount, 'invoice_count' => $invoiceCount]);
  }
});
$this->info('Company count cache updated!');
```

Comment: Just perform a `select count(*) from table limit 1`?

Comment: How do I do that with the nested relationships and the filters on status? @N.B.

Comment: Why do you even use an ORM to perform something that fits a raw database query? Join the tables, perform the filtering, limit it to 1 and get the count. With only 500k rows you should be getting that result in a few milliseconds without wasting any RAM. You don't have to do every single query using eloquent and having complex code.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to do that? @N.B.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain please, what you are trying to achieve, count of active equipments in every company?

Comment: Updated main question

Comment: Sorry, Matthew, I was a little busy. I think your solution is good enough. I sure it's possible to make an complex single SQL query for this, but it's too hard to figure it out without your database schema and data (you can provide migrations and seeds for that). But also I do not see the point to implement this complex SQL if your code already just works. You can add some unit tests for that and forget about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the memory usage problem by converting it to direct SQL queries (4gb+ to 100mb)

```
DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
$start = microtime(true);
Company::chunk(50, function($companies) {
    foreach ($companies as $company) {
        $maintainedCount = 0;
        $equipmentCount = 0; 
        $leadCount = 0;
        $invoiceCount = 0;
        $projectCount = 0; 
        $orderCount = 0;
        $maintainedCount = reset(DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                                    SELECT equipment.id FROM equipment
                                    INNER JOIN agreements ON agreements.id = equipment.agreement_id 
                                    WHERE agreements.company_id = :companyId
                                    AND equipment.status = "Active"
                                    AND (agreements.status = "Active" OR agreements.status = "Unsigned" OR agreements.status = "Cancel on Expiry")) AS QUERY;'), 
                                    ['companyId' => $company->id])[0]);
        $equipmentCount = $company->equipment->where('status', 'Active')->count();
        $unmaintainedCount = ($equipmentCount - $maintainedCount);
        $leadCount= $company->leads->where('status', 'Open')->count();
        $invoiceCount = reset(DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                                            SELECT invoices.id
                                            FROM invoices
                                            WHERE invoices.company_id = :companyId
                                            AND (invoices.status = "Pending" OR invoices.status = "Complete")) AS QUERY;'), 
                                            ['companyId' => $company->id])[0]);         
        $projectCount = reset(DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                                                  SELECT projects.id FROM projects
                                                  INNER JOIN equipment ON equipment.id = projects.equipment_id
                                                  INNER JOIN locations ON locations.id = equipment.location_id
                                                  WHERE locations.company_id = :companyId
                                                  AND (projects.status = "Pending" OR projects.status = "Complete")) AS QUERY;'), 
                                                  ['companyId' => $company->id])[0]);               
        $orderCount = reset(DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                                                SELECT orders.id FROM orders
                                                INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = orders.project_id
                                                INNER JOIN equipment ON equipment.id = projects.equipment_id
                                                INNER JOIN locations ON locations.id = equipment.location_id
                                                WHERE locations.company_id = :companyId
                                                AND (orders.status = "Pending" OR orders.status = "Complete")) AS QUERY;'), 
                                                ['companyId' => $company->id])[0]);
        DB::table('companies')->where('id', $company->id)->update(['unmaintained_count' => $unmaintainedCount, 'lead_count' => $leadCount, 'project_count' => $projectCount, 'order_count' => $orderCount, 'invoice_count' => $invoiceCount]);
    }
});
$duration = number_format((microtime(true) - $start), 2);
$this->info('Company count cache updated! (it took '.$duration.' seconds)');
```